# Which flavors of Linux can work with 3 monitors (2 video cards) without problems?

Tags: linux, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I have one monitor connected to integrated Intel and two monitors connected to my Nvidia 550ti. I installed Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon and have big problems with Nvidia (the last tested driver is already installed).

1. only the intel monitor and 1 nVidia monitor are working. If I'm try turning on other one, I get an error.
2. One monitor which works has a lot of artifacts (in Windows all is ok with 3 monitors).

What I must do? Or, may be, is here better Linux for working with 2 video cards?

Comment: Do you have the proprietary nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: @davidbaumann yes, i have

Comment: What distros have you tried? You can create a USB drive very easily and test the support.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Ubuntu claim to have multiple monitor support. Doing a quick search on the net I do see many different sites devoted to how to set them up for different graphics display or hardware settings. Ubuntu does in fact have a lot of support and updates often.

Comment: I think the same can be said about Debian. Fedora on the other hand has the reputation for being a very commonly used distro *and* for implementing new features very quickly. So I think Fedora should be also taken into consideration...

Comment: Yes they probably can as well, however Debian can be a little daunting. Fedora has great support if you have a very recent distro.